# Preventing event capturing on $( document ).mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a function that's called every time the browser detects a `$( document ).mousemove` event.

Performance is great when there's literally nothing on the page, but as soon as I add a div of some kind and mouse over it, my function is getting called twice: once on the document and then again from the element.

What's the best way for me to work around this, so that the function only triggers once? I thought about instead detecting mousemove on a fullscreen, transparent div, with `pointer-events` set to none, but I suspect this will prevent `mousemove` from even firing in the first place.

I tried `e.stopPropagation()`, but that didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: It will be great if you can show your code in Plunker / JSfiddle

Comment: What you describe should not happen. You might be adding two listeners as there will be only one event fired, from the real target, which will then bubble through its ancestors.

Comment: Okay, here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8eaa401v/

You'll notice it's super smooth when you don't move the mouse over any objects, but as soon as you intersect with them you get jerkiness. E.g. going from top-right to bottom-left, or over the box in the corner.

Comment: Isn't that *jerkiness* you talk about the result of `mouseout`? This event will bubble to the document from any visible elements in the document. I guess that what you want is mouseleave and not mouseout. https://jsfiddle.net/8eaa401v/1/

Comment: Ahhh, thank you so much. I've been scratching my head over this one, and hadn't come across the differences between `mouseout` and `mouseleave` before.

Answer (score 1):

Close but not quite.

You want [`e.stopimmediatepropagation`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/) which calls `e.stopPropagation()` in addition to preventing other elements from being called.

Comment: No luck. :( Here's a JSFiddle, if it helps: https://jsfiddle.net/8eaa401v/